# all process are in sleeping in top command for a couple of days

Tags: sleep-wake, memory, activity-monitor

I am seeing All the process are in "sleeping" state, What is the process thats causing all the issue.
CPU is not used much, 4GB memory is used up showing in activity monitor. If you could find the process thats doing this nasty that would be of great help.

Few of my observation

1. kernel_task has spawned more than 100 threads.
   [image]
2. mds_store is taking more memory which is spotlight indexing
   [image]
3. mds_store read disk is in GB, is it trying to index and the index is stopped for somereason hence all process is in sleeping state

Or It could be something really different.
[image]

4. Here is the output of top command
   All process are sleeping state, this is really strange and my computer is hogging / very slow.

[image]

Comment: Is there actually a problem?

Comment: My mac has become very very sluggish

Comment: Problem didnt go away for more than two days every after several restarts and few safe boot.

Comment: CPU and RAM usage seems very low. What model Mac is this?

Comment: MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) - 8GB Ram - Processor 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7

Comment: Are you saying the problem still occurs while in Safe Boot mode, or just "after" a quick Safe Boot, then normal restart? Also, you should test the behaviour in a brand new user account.

Comment: The problem (slugishness) is sort of solved in new user a/c but the process are sleeping. I am really getting curious to know whats going wrong.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using `top`, I see most processes listed as 'sleeping', so I don't think that is indicative of a problem, in itself.

You have identified that the problem of sluggishness goes away in a brand new user account. That is a test to pinpoint the cause, not a solution. (Don't migrate to the new user account.)

The cause is likely to be some background process that is triggered in your old account. Look at Login Items, and Launch Agents and Launch Daemons in your user Library.

It could also be user caches that have become corrupt; or perhaps some user settings that are somehow causing a problem, though that's rarer.